# How to update final object using callback data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object with keys id,name like below. Based on the id i have to get customer name and update the object.

```
    Const arr=[{id:1,name:''},{id:2,name:''}];
    
    
    _.forEach (arr, function (obj)){
    const result=getcustomer(obj.id, function (data){
    //Getting customer data here.
    });

}
```

How can i update obj.name for each object when i get data asynchronously?

Comment: What happens when you put obj.name = data instead of your comment?

Answer (score 0):

Would you not just get the index of the item you are currently on and update that array element? Or am I missing something here.

```
arr.forEach((item, index) => {
   const result = await getCustomer(item.id);
   arr[index].name = result.data.name; //however you get the data
  });
```